# Multi-language Excel VBA Macro (French / English / Swedish)

Tags: excel, internationalization, vba

Good evening!

I have developed a macro in English on a Swedish Mac. The macro runs on a a Mac used in France with Excel in French. All the Subroutines work very well... but one. I used the formula "=VALUTA(123,4567)" [Swedish for currency] so that it should truncate to 2 decimals and then convert to text. The corresponding French formula is "=DEVISE(123,4567)", which I now use. I fill a whole column with this formula with the VBA-macro but the result is "NOM?" [name?]; one would think Excel does not recognize DEVISE().

However, and this is the real question, if I mark any of these cells and press RETURN (manually, that is) it recognizes the formula and prints 123,45!!!

I am quite frustrated. Any pointers towards a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That sounds incredibly frustrating. Ive never used international versions but are English commands allowed on either of those versions?  You fill a column with a VBA Macro?  I think you're mixing your terms up What is the name of the Macro you developed?  There are certain names you can't use, and the `NOM` error indicates either a bad name or an unknown name. I don't think you are using VALUTA/DEVISE incorrectly.  CURRENCY is not the name of an English function.Could you edit your Question to add your code?  Also, Google to find the syntax (how to use)VALUTA & DEVISE and post the links here?

Comment: Thank you very much. The code is very simple: 
       ' Fetch values and convert to "text' with two decimals (works as written above)
       ActiveSheet.Range("AL13:AL129").Formula = "=DEVISE(C13)"
       ActiveSheet.Range("AM13:AM129").Formula = "=DEVISE(F14)"

The Swedish version (works nicely in my Mac):

       ActiveSheet.Range("AL13:AL129").Formula = "=VALUTA(C13)"
       ActiveSheet.Range("AM13:AM129").Formula = "= VALUTA(F14)"
Be so kind as to have a look here: https://fr.excel-translator.de/translator/

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. The code uses ROUNDDOWN() to 2 decimals [which is OK but not really want I wanted] which also works in French Excel, rather than DEVISE(). After that I use concatenation to get the values of with two decimals. If I do not use ROUNDDOWN(), the result will be "Place: 2.34567". So this is what I have now:

`ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Formula = "= LOOKUP(2,1/(H:H>1),H:H)"
    ActiveSheet.Range("AJ138")=ROUNDDOWN(A5,2)
    ActiveSheet.Range("AQ13:AQ129").Formula = "=""Place: ""&AJ13&"`

That is the best I can do. Thank you all for responding. I will post another question, how to get the address found by the lookup function.